# vue load synchonous initialization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I have a program written in vue and electron.
This program calls an `init` function that takes around 15 seconds to complete.

The issue I am having is that I can't seem to make this run in a background thread or after the component has rendered a loading view. The application is just a white blank screen while the init function is running.

I would assume that it would be easiest to just load a `loading` view and let it be frozen during startup, so how would I actually go about doing that?

I tested with something like this:

```
  updated() {
    console.log("running init");
    init();
    this.loading = false;
    console.log("completed init");
  }
```

but it appears as if it isn't always called.
To force it I updated some data in the `mounted` hook, but then it freezes on the white screen

Comment: 15 seconds of blocking js code?! 

Comment: Start by putting the code in a `setTimeout`: `setTimeout(() => { init(); this.loading = false; }, 0)`

Comment: @RoyJ that actually works. Thanks!